# Android Fragment detach

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, detach

I have an activity with two fragments. One fragment is shown in portrait, the other in landscape mode. The fragments are added with java.

```
Fragment fragment = null;
        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            fragment = new FragmentPortrait();
        } else {
            fragment = new FragmentLandscape();
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            addFragment(fragment, savedInstanceState == null);
        }

private void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean add) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();

        detachFragment("fragment");

        if (add) {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layoutForFragment, fragment,
                    "fragment");
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layoutForFragment,
                    fragment, "fragment");
        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

private void detachFragment(String fragmentTag) {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                fragmentTag);

        if (fragment != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "detaching");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that if I started my activity in Portrait mode and when I rotate the screen the landscape fragment is shown as expected but onActivityCreated in the portrait fragment is called too. This means that the portrait fragment still exists. Can you tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: You don't need to detach fragments manually. Just try to replace them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Keep it simple`**:: `Replacing Fragment` = `Removing Current Fragment` + `Adding New Fragment`

---

**`Sample`**:: *Modify to your needs with `saveInstance` and other things*

---

```
Boolean mFlag=false;
{
        Fragment fragment = null; 

        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        if(mFlag==false) 
            FragmentPortrait();
            mFlag=true; 
        } else { 
        if(mFlag==true)
            FragmentLandscape();
            mFlag=false;
        } 

        FragmentPortrait(){
         // Perform Action:: Replacing a fragment with the fragment you want to add in Portrait
        }

        FragmentLandscape(){
        // Perform Action:: Replacing a fragment with the fragment you want to add in Landscape
        }

}
```

Comment: I didn't have the detaching method before but noticed that problem and tried with it but it still doesn't work.. I will fix my code, but can you tell me when I change (for example) from portrait to landscape why the onActivityCreated of the portrait is also called?

Comment: @ Crash-ID .... `onActivityCreated` will be called since the fragment is destroyed and created ! ....... But i have no idea why `OnOrientation` change from portrait to landscape why the `onActivityCreated` of the portrait is also called ........ If you want to prevent this try by restricting by using `flags` ... Since the global variables are not destroyed in class `OnOrientation` change ! ...... Check the edit !! .... hope it helps ...`Note-` Modify the flag setup to your needs !